# SQL Stored Procedure fired from C# Code-Behind not working on UPDATE

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure called from a C# code-behind. The code fires but the update command does not get performed. The stored procedure, if run directly, works. I think I am having a brain fart. Please help.

Code:

```
protected void btnAbout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("spUpdateCMSAbout", myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@AboutText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = txtAbout.Text.ToString();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE fstage.spUpdateCMSAbout
(
   @AboutText nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE fstage.staticCMS SET About = @AboutText;
END
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAbout" runat="server" 
    Text="Save" CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnAbout_Click" 
    UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

C# .NET 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work. However you can simplify it a little and make more robust:

```
using(var myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
using(var myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myCommand.CommandText = "spUpdateCMSAbout";
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("AboutText", txtAbout.Text);
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If it does not, try bypassing your stored proc by calling `UPDATE` directly:

```
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
using (var myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE fstage.staticCMS SET About = @AboutText";
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("AboutText", txtAbout.Text);
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If it does not work, than it is likely `UPDATE fstage.staticCMS SET About = 'something'` does not do anything because of some kind of trigger.

Comment: I directly went and tried you update method which is more compact (gracias!) and it didn't work.  I began to look at the data I was inputting and it have these characters :  DC’s Center®.   Will this affect a update? The length of the data being input is 491 characters which shouldn't be an issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CSSHell - No, content of txtAbout.Text should not affect `UPDATE` statement execution.

Comment: fyi when I go into a query window and do a spUpdateCMSAbout 'my text that is 500 chars long.' it does the insert fine.

Comment: @CSSHell - are you sure that your connection string is actually pointed to the correct server instance. You probably updating on one instance, but checking results on another.

Comment: @CSSHell - also, try to replace `CommandType.StoredProcedure` in the first code sample, with `CommandType.Text`. This should work too.

Comment: The strConnection is in the web.config and retrieved as a global outside the functions.

Comment: should your second example use .AddWithValue("@AboutText" ?

Comment: Welp, let me start by saying YES - IT WAS A BRAINFART. Second, thank you for your help and if nothing else you provided me with nicely compact code. I thank you so much for your help. BTW, I had my fillContentTextBox out side of the !isPostBack. Doh!  If I could give you a check++ I would. Have a great night.

Answer (score 0):

I would always run SQL Server Profiler and set a trace on your database. You can be sure then if your database is getting the query. If it is then you know the problem is in your DB, if it isn't then you know it's your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void uiUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usb_update_empdtls", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        SqlParameter parEmployeeID = AddInputParameters("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox1.Text);

        SqlParameter parLastName = AddInputParameters("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox2.Text);
        SqlParameter parFirstName = AddInputParameters("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox3.Text);
        SqlParameter parTitle = AddInputParameters("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox4.Text);
        SqlParameter parPresentAddress = AddInputParameters("@PresentAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox5.Text);
        SqlParameter parCity = AddInputParameters("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox6.Text);
        SqlParameter parPostalCode = AddInputParameters("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox7.Text);
        SqlParameter parCountry = AddInputParameters("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox8.Text);
        SqlParameter parExtension = AddInputParameters("@Extension", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, TextBox9.Text);
        SqlParameter parResult = AddOutputParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parEmployeeID);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parLastName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parFirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parPresentAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parCity);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parPostalCode);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parCountry);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parExtension);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parResult);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        uiResultLabel.Visible = true;
        uiResultLabel.Text = "updated Successfully";
    }
}
```